# sql azure beginner- getting error for an simple insert statement

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I am trying to insert a row of data into a table in SQL Azure --

This is the insert statement--

```
INSERT INTO cloud_storage_credentials (cloud_provider,api_key, api_secret)
VALUES("Rackspace", "<random_value>", "<random_value>");
```

However I am getting the following error--

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'Rackspace'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name '<random_value>'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name '<random_value>'.
```

What am I doing wrong here? I followed an SQL Server tutorial to write the above query...

Comment: Don't put double quotes in data. Use single quotes: `'Rackspace'`

Comment: @ypercube Thanks. It works now... kindly put your comment as a solution and I will accept it as the answer for this query...

Comment: There are 2 answers below that say the same thing. You can choose one of them. If I am not wrong, SQLMenace answered seconds before my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `"` (double quotes) to `'` (tick/single quote)

```
INSERT INTO cloud_storage_credentials (cloud_provider,api_key, api_secret)
VALUES('Rackspace', '<random_value>', '<random_value>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `"`s with `'`s. As it is, it thinks that the values you are inserting are name of columns.